# How to open a database i just created using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I just created a simple database using python in visual studio code but where should i look for the database i just created. I am using sqlite (db browser) and couldn't find my databse. Please help me am stuck in this i have been searching all over the internet since 1 hour but culdn't find anything useful.

Comment: Show us you code please

Comment: Hi AsihwaryV, welcome to SO. Please strongly consider posting a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of both HTML and CSS (and JS if applicable or other lang.) so we can better help you thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you the DB was created via python code - you had to give the file name of the DB. This is the file you should find on disk and point your DB Browser to.

you should have code that looks like

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

Are you sure DB was created? Did you create any table?

Comment: Thank you i got it! i wasn't opening a folder in vs code maybe cos of that i couldn't find it. Anyway thnk you, am good